# Is there any workaround for arrays in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

Arrays are not available in PineScript.

Is there any workaround? Has anyone developed a code, which works as array?

What do I need it for? I would like to count number of touches to each trendline or S/R level.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not seen any workarounds for arrays. However, it is possible to implement a counter if that’s what you need. If you show me some code regarding how you get the trendline or S/R levels, I can help you with that.

Comment: Thanks. So this is the code for S/R levels. Ideally I would like to have an array of these with a counter of touches with those lines. https://www.tradingview.com/script/JwWWwZOD-RSI-MTF-by-PeterO/

Comment: READ THIS!!  Pine Script now supports arrays natively.  Read here https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Arrays.html  

NOTE TO EDITORS:  The question itself NEEDS to be updated with this info but I was not able to because the EDIT que is full.

Answer (score 4):

To implement a counter, you can create a variable and then modify its value by using the **History Referencing Operator** `[]`.

Below example counts number of crossover/crossunder occurrences in a typical rsi diagram.

```
//@version=3
study("counter", overlay=false)

rsi_max = 70
rsi_min = 30

cnt_up = 0
cnt_dwn = 0

cnt_up := crossover(rsi(close, 14), rsi_max) ? nz(cnt_up[1]) + 1 : nz(cnt_up[1])
cnt_dwn := crossunder(rsi(close, 14), rsi_min) ? nz(cnt_dwn[1]) + 1 : nz(cnt_dwn[1])

plot(rsi(close, 14), color=orange, title='RSI')
plot(series=cnt_up, title="Up counter", color=green)
plot(series=cnt_dwn, title="Down counter", color=red)

band0 = hline(30)
band1 = hline(70)
fill(band1, band0, color=purple, transp=90)
```

Green line is the "cnt_up" in my example. After that point, rsi line crosses over the "overbought" zone 7 more times.

[image]

And here, you can see that "cnt_up" indeed counted up 7 times.

[image]

Unfortunately, this is all you can do.

Comment: Thanks Baris. Yes, I knew how to do the counter. The challenge with counting touches to S/R levels is that there can be multiple S/R levels and we don't know how many of them and the goal is to add counter to each of them. As far as I know, this is where arrays come in handy. But like we said - there is no native implementation of arrays and this might be the reason why I'll have to learn another language to code this.

Answer (score 3):

recently they add arrays and you can use it like this:
[reference](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Arrays.html?highlight=array)

```
levels = array.new_int(size = 5, initial_value = na)
for i = 1 to 5
    array.push(levels, i)
```

there is no direct access to array element and you must use it like this

```
array.get(levels, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

RicardoSantos create a pseudo array function. See his [Pseudo Array Example](https://www.tradingview.com/script/sQxpiBL8-RS-Function-Pseudo-Array-Example/).

Answer (score -2):

I do not see an official method to create array in Pine Script. However, you can simulate it by walk backward at every new bar/tick/calculation and see how many touches in the past. I'd go for other languages such as C# with separate data feed for this work.